# What is the difference between Builder Pattern with static inner class and Builder design patterns with One Abstract and one+ concrete implimentations

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, builder

I am learning about builder design pattern, I found two explanations of the same.

1. With a static inner builder class which returns object of outer class appropriately.
2. With One Builder Abstract class, then more than one implementations of the same and one director class.
   [image]

I am totally confuse over which one it is? or is it both?

Comment: both of them are appropriately.The difference is  for 1, other classes will have no access to this concreateBuilder class, compare to 2 which other classes will still have access to it. If you have only one class extends from Builder, 1 is a good choice. But when you have several classes extends it,  it is confusion that you treat concreateBuilder as static inner builder class.

Comment: @user9594794  fair point! but we can accommodate both types of builder (case 2) in case 1 of Builder pattern also, using setters/methods (and optionally choosing not to set some properties), isn't? what are the downsides of that?

Comment: take a look at  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern#:~:text=The%20builder%20pattern%20is%20a,Gang%20of%20Four%20design%20patterns.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is both... and more. There are numerous patterns originating from different sources that are all referred to as "Builder". This is not so unusual as you might think; for example, there are numerous different patterns all referred to as "Factory" as well.

Regarding the two you mention.

1. The static inner Builder was popularized by Josh Bloch in his book, *Effective Java*.
2. The abstract polymorphic Builder was popularized by the GoF in their seminal *Design Patterns* book.

There are more useful Builder patterns from other sources as well. See: [Builder isomorphisms](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/02/10/builder-isomorphisms/).

Comment: very true! I read static inner Builder on Josh Bloch blog only. Thank you this insightful answer.